# Android View setPadding() vs setPaddingRelative()

Tags: android, android-view, padding

Based on the Android [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) which doesn't give much explanation, what's the difference between `setPadding()` vs `setPaddingRelative()`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`setPaddingRelative` has this code inside:

```
switch(getResolvedLayoutDirection()) {
        case LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL:
            setPadding(end, top, start, bottom);
            break;
        case LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR:
        default:
            setPadding(start, top, end, bottom);
}
```

So when you set padding with `setPaddingRelative` it changes left and right padding values depending on user's layout direction.

Comment: God, they chosen a misleading name for that. I though that this means "adjust padding relative to the current values", so setPaddingRelative(0, 10, 5, 0) would increase top padding by 10 and right padding by 5. I really miss such function sometimes...

Comment: ViewCompat#setPaddingRelative can automatically call either setPaddingRelative if RTL is supported, or setPadding if it's not (i.e. pre-API 17), if you care about that sort of thing